# Should we add placeholders for referencing upvotes, downvotes, views, etc. of a question/answer?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, markdown, views

Often when writing meta posts, you are referencing values such as upvotes, downvotes, and views from other questions. This results in lots of "at the time of writing" and "currently", rather than their exact current values.

A potential solution would be to add some way of referencing these values, using some formatting, e.g., maybe *$stackexchange.codegolf.q.231022.views* would return the number of views from *[Recursive Z-matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231022/recursive-z-matrix)*, format in reference to Unix-based variables.

Another potential formatting option: *%se.codegolf.q.231022%.getViews*, which would return the same as the other. Also an option, you could have after *getViews* (if you use the get one), could be replaced with *getViews()*, and maybe even a time period within the parenthesis (as in programming getters).

Other variations are of course possible, and would make sense as well. Whatever would make most sense to the community as a whole.

Also, you could replace views or getViews with *upvotes*, *getUpvotes*, or *upv/getUpv*, and similar for downvotes (*dnv*, etc.).

Comment: What is the value of having "live update" for these numbers? Often when writing meta posts we are trying to make a more general point the *exact number* of upvotes/downvotes/views/etc.

Comment: A lot of the time it makes sense to have these values as they were at the time of posting and live updates could make the question not make sense when asking about specific cases.

Comment: Live updating could also drastically alter the meaning of a post and invalidate existing answers.

Comment: Image a post with zero views and the OP asks "why does nobody look at my Q". The post might get a lot of views later.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz That actually really changed my  mind on the situation. THank you for writing this, it makes a huge difference to my perspective.

Comment: @CATboardBETA You're welcome!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Live updates would have the risk of drastically changing posts and potentially invalidating existing answers.

As a silly example, a users might ask

> Why does nobody look at my question, it only has 1 view

Over time this could become

> Why does nobody look at my question, it only has 10000000000000000 views